# how do i fix problem for adding an Image on xml file for android development..?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

In my xml code, for android development, I'm facing a problem when adding an image on screen.

[image]

my image `I1` is working fine...
but problem occurs when I use image `I2` in my code. I don't know why but my app crashes when I open it using `I2` image. but I've used `I1` instead of `I2`. Then it works properly.

Why it is happening ...??
is there any solution....??

Comment: please provide crash log

Comment: please check the size/resolution of the image.If it is too big app will crash

Answer (score 0):

The app crashes because there is an `OutOfMemoryException` since loading the image into the ImageView is too large for the app to handle that.

What you need to do is to use some library that is already optimized for managing images

Try using

https://square.github.io/picasso/

or

https://github.com/bumptech/glide

To load the image into the ImageView